# Como enviar o valor de um radio com o id do usuário concatenado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Bom dia minha duvida e complexa esto criando um sistema que vai criar card de cada usuário cadastrado, para diferenciar os card cada elemento do card possui o id do usuário. Gostaria de saber como capturo o valor do radio selecionado, só que o nome do radio esta concatenado com o id do usuario para poder se diferenciar dos demais card.

olhem so os codigos :

ESTE CRIA O CARD

```
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<div class=" cardUser col-md-12">
    <div class="cardNome">
    <span>'.$registro['nome'].'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cardPro">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"> '.$registro['idProfissao'].'</span>
    <span class="cardPro2 glyphicon glyphicon-education"> '.$registro['idProfissao2'].'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cardInfo">
    <ul class="cardUl">
    <li class="cardLi">
    <span class="cardValue glyphicon glyphicon-globe"> '.$registro['idCidade'].'</span>
    <span class="cardValue glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" id="tel"> '.$registro['telefone'].'</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="estrelas">
    <ul class="cardUl">
    <li class="cardLi">
    <span class="cardLabel">Status:</span>
    <span class="cardValue"> '.$registro['disponibilidade'].'</span>
    </li>
    <li class="cardLi">
    <Form id="estrelas"> 
    <span class="cardLabel">Avaliação:</span>              
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-empty-'.$registro['id'].'" name="fb'.$registro['id'].'" value="" checked/>
    <label for="cm_star-1-'.$registro['id'].'"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1-'.$registro['id'].'" name="fb'.$registro['id'].'" value="1"/>
    <label for="cm_star-2-'.$registro['id'].'"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2-'.$registro['id'].'" name="fb'.$registro['id'].'" value="2"/>
    <label for="cm_star-3-'.$registro['id'].'"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3-'.$registro['id'].'" name="fb'.$registro['id'].'" value="3"/>
    <label for="cm_star-4-'.$registro['id'].'"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4-'.$registro['id'].'" name="fb'.$registro['id'].'" value="4"/>
    <label for="cm_star-5-'.$registro['id'].'"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5-'.$registro['id'].'" name="fb'.$registro['id'].'" value="5"/>
    </Form>
    </li>        
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-like" id="btn-like-'.$registro['id'].'" data-id_usuario="'.$registro['id'].'">Avaliar</button>        
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

Este e codigo js que uso para enviar as variaves o id do usuario eu consigo capturar mais o valor do radio nao sei como fazer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('.btn-like').click(function(){
        var id_usuario = $(this).data('id_usuario');
        var estrela = $(this).data('');


        $('#btn-like-'+id_usuario).hide();

        $.ajax({
           url: 'like.php',
           method: 'post',
            data: { like_id_usuario: id_usuario,  },
            success:function (data) {
                alert('Registro realizado com sucesso');
            }
        });

   });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar o `slice` para extrair só parte da string da ID depois do tamanho do sufixo que tens. Um exemplo seria:

```js
$('.btn-like').click(function() {
  var id_usuario = this.id.slice(9);

  $(this).hide();
  console.log('Utilizador: ' + id_usuario);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-like-1" class="btn-like">Utilizador 1</button>
<button id="btn-like-5" class="btn-like">Utilizador 5</button>
<button id="btn-like-15" class="btn-like">Utilizador 15</button>
```

Comment: Boa tarde Sérgio agradeço sua disponibilidade em me ajudar,  no exemplo vc usou o id do botão para capturar a informação. Mais como faço isso com rádio  onde é usado o name para passar o valor? Tipo meu rádio tem o name=fb(+id do usuário recuperado no select) o mesmo tem este nome para diferenciar um card do outro para poder manipular um rádio sem afetar o outro card. Como faço para este contexto sabe me informar. Se puder ser o mais didático possível agradeço pós sou novo na área.

Comment: @MaykeAlisson podes clarificar qual é o botão que clicas e de qual `radio` queres extraír o valor? Queres ambos o ID do utilizador e o valor do `radio`?

Comment: consegui fazer funcionar obrigado.